# flake8 config file not present by default

Tags: flake8

I have installed flake8 using pip on Ubuntu but I don't have any flake8 config file at '~/.config' by default. Can someone pointout a possible reason  for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Flake8 does not create default configuration files. Flake8's default behaviour is considered reasonable. If you wish, you can create a `~/.config/flake8` file and add something like:

```
[flake8]
max-line-length = 100
```

For example, and that should suffice.

Also, keep in mind that most any option you can specify on the command-line can be specified in your config file. Most people opt to use per-project configuration files instead, however, because that allows other contributors to that project to see the same errors and messages that you would.

Comment: I am trying to use StyleGuide() to take in the errors occuring  in a file.Which method can i use ?( I want the errors but not number of errors)

Comment: Ask a new question. That's entirely unrelated to this.